# What causes init script conflict when compiling?

Tags: meta-raspberrypi

I assume the kas-poky-rpi.yml was intended to work out of the box, but I get the following error.

Can someone offer some advice or hints which files does this refer to and any insights on the repo error?

I cloned the openbmc repo.

I also tried to run kas from an empty dir with the same error.

### Error

kas build meta-raspberrypi/kas-poky-rpi.yml

2020-06-15 14:30:14 - INFO     - kas 2.1.1 started

…

2020-06-15 14:30:42 - ERROR    - Multiple init scripts found (openbmc vs. poky). 
2020-06-15 14:30:42 - ERROR    - Resolve ambiguity by removing one of the repos